# What does [,...n] mean in T-SQL BNF?

Tags: t-sql, bnf

If you look at this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499 What does the `[,...n]` mean? I have my suspicions that it's just Microsoft's alternative to using the sequence `{ }` symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That [nice big link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563) right above the Syntax block on those MSDN pages lays out their "conventions." For `[,...n]`, it has this to say:

> Indicates the preceding item can be repeated n number of times. The
>   occurrences are separated by commas.

Comment: To be fair, it'd be far more obvious (at least to me) if that link were *below* the syntax block, or at least below the "Syntax" heading, so it was actually part of that section.

Answer (score 0):

It means an optional number of N repetitions.

Square Brackets denote optional parts of the statement. So for example, you can have a `SELECT` statement without an `ORDER BY` clause.